# How to map high symmetry points from primitive cell to conventional cell?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, computational-physics

We usually plot electronic bands with the help of high symmetry points of the irreducible zone of primitive cell of particular material. But if we want to plot bands with conventional cell, we have to map the high symmetry points from primitive cell to conventional cell.
so how can we map the high symmetry points from primitive cell to conventional cell ?? basically how can we transform the points ?

Comment: Populate the conventional cell with unit cells. Trim if needed keeping symmetry in mind.

Comment: Dear Jon . I did not get your point clearly. can you please elaborate ??

Comment: Cross-posted to MatterModeling.SE: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9169/671